# Once after reboot - Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=742, result=-1,data=null}

Tags: android, debugging, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, stack-trace

First, I know its a commonly occuring error and that there is a lot of questions about this one. The thing is that it only happen once after a complete shutdown and reboot AND the debugger won't allow me to inspect what is hapenning.

Here is the code that starts the Activity

```
protected File mediaTemp = null;

private void addPictures() {
    try {
        // On prends et enregistre la photo
        MediafileHelper mediaHelper = new MediafileHelper(this);
        mediaTemp = mediaHelper
                .createMediaFile(MediafileHelper.PICTURE_FILE_EXT);
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(mediaTemp));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                MediafileHelper.PICTURE_ACTION_CODE);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    int i = 1;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MediafileHelper.PICTURE_ACTION_CODE:
/*Line 240*/ if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && mediaTemp.exists()) {
                // Ajout de l'image à la collection.
                Mediafile mediaFile = new Mediafile(
                        Mediafile.TYPE_PICTURE_JPG, mediaTemp);
                mediaFile.setCaptureDatetime(new Date());
                mediaFile.setLocation(REAC.getLocationHelper()
                        .getCurrentLocation());
                medias.add(mediaFile);
                addPictures();
            } else {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && !mediaTemp.exists()) {
                    // Le fichier n'a pas pu être créé pour une raison hors
                    // de notre contrôle. (Appel téléphonique ou autre)
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            getString(R.string.mediafile_file_not_created),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // On rafraichis la liste des médias.
                mediasFragment.getMediafileAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;

        case MediafileHelper.VIDEO_ACTION_CODE:
        ...
    }
}
```

And finally, the stack trace

```
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.teops.qsl.reac/com.teops.qsl.reac.PicturesActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=742, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.teops.qsl.reac/com.teops.qsl.reac.PicturesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2642)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2670)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4967)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=742, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.teops.qsl.reac/com.teops.qsl.reac.PicturesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3208)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): ... 12 more
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at com.teops.qsl.reac.mediafile.MediafileActivity.onActivityResult(MediafileActivity.java:240)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5344)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3204)
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): ... 13 more
09-27 10:01:26.660 D/ActivityThread( 4363): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
09-27 10:01:26.660 D/ActivityThread( 4363): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
09-27 10:01:26.660 D/ActivityThread( 4363): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
09-27 10:01:26.740 D/LocationHelper( 4363): Location : Location[mProvider=network,mTime=1380290486532,mLatitude=46.7949937,mLongitude=-71.2240393,mHasAltitude=false,mAltitude=0.0,mHasSpeed=false,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0,mHasAccuracy=true,mAccuracy=20.0,mExtras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=148]]
09-27 10:01:27.010 I/Adreno200-EGLSUB( 4363): <ConfigWindowMatch:2136>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-27 10:01:27.020 E/        ( 4363): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
09-27 10:01:27.020 E/        ( 4363): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
```

So one will tell me that something is wrong there

```
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 10:01:09.211 E/AndroidRuntime( 4094): at com.teops.qsl.reac.mediafile.MediafileActivity.onActivityResult(MediafileActivity.java:240)
```

I placed a breakpoint at `int i = 1;` (line 238) to be able to debug the next few lines, but the debugger won't stop there, my application crashes with this log.

I placed a `try{} catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}` around the content of the CASE. It does not crash the application, but instead of continuing takeing pictures, it comes back to the Activity, the picture is not added to the collection and the StackTrace is not printed. A brakepoint on `e.printStackTrace()` does not brake.

```
            try {
                // Résultat de "Prise de photo"
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && mediaTemp.exists()) {
                    // Ajout de l'image à la collection.
                    Mediafile mediaFile = new Mediafile(
                            Mediafile.TYPE_PICTURE_JPG, mediaTemp);
                    mediaFile.setCaptureDatetime(new Date());
                    mediaFile.setLocation(REAC.getLocationHelper()
                            .getCurrentLocation());
                    medias.add(mediaFile);
                    addPictures();
                } else {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && !mediaTemp.exists()) {
                        // Le fichier n'a pas pu être créé pour une raison
                        // hors
                        // de notre contrôle. (Appel téléphonique ou autre)
                        Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                getString(R.string.mediafile_file_not_created),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // On rafraichis la liste des médias.
                    mediasFragment.getMediafileAdapter()
                            .notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In every case, the picture is saved on the file represented by `mediaTemp`.

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error was occuring on this line of code

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && !mediaTemp.exists()) {
```

I don't know why the debugger could not stop, but I found the reason why the NPE was occuring.
The variable `mediaTemp` was indeed null. The reason for this is that Android was destroying my activity and recreating it when needed (after the picture is taken). It is a documented behavior of android activity lifecycle. Why was it only happening once after the boot... let ask to the Green Android.

The solution is to override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` or change your `onCreate` accordingly.

First, you save important data when the activity is destroyed or stopped :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Enregistrement du fichier temporaire.
    if (mediaTemp != null) {
        outState.putSerializable(MEDIATEMP_FILE_BUNDLE, mediaTemp);
    }

    // Enregistrement de la liste de Mediafiles.
    if (medias != null && medias.size() != 0) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(MEDIAS_LIST_BUNDLE, medias);
    }

}
```

And you either load it in the `onRestoreInstanceState()` or like I did, manage it in the `onCreate` :

```
    // Restauration des données enregistrées, si applicable.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restauration du fichier temporaire.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(MEDIATEMP_FILE_BUNDLE)) {
            mediaTemp = (File) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(MEDIATEMP_FILE_BUNDLE);
        }

        // Restauration de la liste de Mediafiles.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(MEDIAS_LIST_BUNDLE)) {
            medias = savedInstanceState
                    .getParcelableArrayList(MEDIAS_LIST_BUNDLE);
        }
    } else {
        // Données par défaut
        medias = new ArrayList<Mediafile>();
    }
```

I hope this can help someone having similar issues in the future.